# Highcharts having trouble setting a responsive pointwidth

Tags: highcharts

Team!

I've created a highcharts with drilldown features and scrolling -- it's pretty slick if I do say so myself :).  I'm having one final issue making it a perfect chart, and that's when I look at it on a mobile phone/xs screen size, the column bars are "scrunching in" as close as they possibly can, to the point that it's almost unreadable.

I've been playing around with the responsive feature on highcharts and I've set the pointpadding and grouppadding to widen the bars as far as they can.  I also tried using pointWidth, but that just allowed the bars to overlay on top of each other.

The only other solution I can think of is to try to widen the plot area but I can't find a way to do that -- chart.wide widens the entire chart, but I want it to stay smaller than the width of the device.

Does anybody have any ideas what I can try get the columns to widen?  Here's a [link](https://assessment.jefferson.kyschools.us/DMC/District%20Datacard/ddReferrals) to the graph. To see what I'm talking about, just shrink the width down of your browser as small as it will go, and click on any of the columns in the first graph.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!!

```
//Build The Chart
var refChart = new Highcharts.chart('ctReferralsDetail', {
    chart: {
        backgroundColor: 'whiteSmoke',
        type: 'column',
        width: chartWidth,
        events: {
            drilldown: function (e) {
                var dt = $('#tblReferrals').DataTable();
                dt.destroy();

                $('#tblReferrals thead').empty();
                $('#tblReferrals tbody').empty();

                loadTableDetail(e.point.name);

                if (!e.seriesOptions) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < drilldown.length; i++) {
                        if (e.point.name == drilldown[i]) {
                            this.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, pyDet[i]);
                            this.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, cyDet[i]);
                            this.applyDrilldown();

                            var maxVal = (pyDet[i].categories.length - 1) < chartMax ? pyDet[i].categories.length - 1 : chartMax;

                            this.update({
                                xAxis: {
                                    categories: pyDet[i].categories,
                                    max: maxVal,
                                },
                                exporting: {
                                    sourceHeight: 475,
                                    sourceWidth: pyDet[i].categories * 4.5,
                                    chartOptions: {
                                        xAxis: [{
                                            categories: pyDet[i].categories,
                                            labels: {
                                                rotation: 90
                                            },
                                            max: pyDet[i].categories.length - 1,
                                        }]
                                    },

                                }
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            drillupall: function () {
                var dt = $('#tblReferrals').DataTable();
                dt.destroy();

                $('#tblReferrals thead').empty();
                $('#tblReferrals tbody').empty();

                loadTableSummary();

                this.update({
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: categoriesAA,
                        max: (categoriesAA.length - 1) < chartMax ? categoriesAA.length - 1 : chartMax
                    },
                    exporting: {
                        sourceHeight: 350,
                        sourceWidth: 500,
                        chartOptions: {
                            xAxis: [{
                                categories: categoriesAA,
                                labels: {
                                    rotation: 0
                                },
                                max: categoriesAA.length - 1,
                            }]
                        },
                    }
                })
            },
        },
    },
    title: {
        text: title
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: subTitle
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: categoriesAA,
        min: 0,
        max: (categoriesAA.length - 1) < chartMax ? categoriesAA.length - 1 : chartMax,
        scrollbar: {
            enabled: true
        },
    },
    yAxis: [{
        title: {
            useHtml: true,
            text: '<strong># Referrals</strong>'
        }
    }],
    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            borderRadius: 5,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                allowOverlap: true,
            },
            groupPadding: 0.15,
            pointPadding: 0.05
        },
    },
    series: [{
        name: dataLabels[0],
        data: pyAA
    }, {
        name: dataLabels[1],
        data: cyAA
    }],
    drilldown: {
        allowPointDrilldown: false,
    },
    exporting: {
        scale: 1,
        sourceHeight: 350,
        sourceWidth: 500,
        chartOptions: {
            xAxis: [{
                categories: categoriesAA,
                labels: {
                    rotation: 0
                },
                max: categoriesAA.length - 1,
            }]
        },
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 575
            },

            chartOptions: {
                chart: {
                    width: chartWidth + 75,
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        groupPadding: 0,
                        pointPadding: 0,
                    }
                }
            }

        }]
    }
})
```

Comment: Could you prepare a simplified online demo (for example jsfiddle) of your chart with sample data?

Comment: Sorry it took so long to respond...trying to juggle a lot of balls at the moment.  Here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/BigSexy/aq9Laaew/289601/ that shows what I'm talking about: instead of the columns scrunching together, i'd rather them keep their default width and spacing and just be scrollable...

Comment: For me, the chart on mobile looks pretty good. I removed your responsive roles: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2me4aspo/1/ , check on mobile: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2me4aspo/1/show